# Async Flows Design in Lagom or Microservices

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, lagom

How to design asyn flows in Lagom ?

Problem faced: In our product we have a Lead Aggregate which has a User Id (represents the owner of the lead), Now User has a limitation which says one user can have max of 10 Lead associated with this. We designed this by creating a separate Service ResourceManagement and when a User asks for Picking a Lead, we send a Command to LeadAggregate which generates a Event LeadPickRequested. On ProcessManager Listen to the event and asks for the Resource From ResourceManagement, on Success send Command to LeadAggregate - MarkAsPicked and on this send Push notification to the User that Lead is Picked but from building the UI perspective its very difficult and same cannot be done for exposing our API to third party.

One Sol. we have done is when request is received on Service save a RequestID Vs Request Future . in Command Add the request Id and when the LeadAggregate finally change into Picked State or Picked Failure a PM listen to the event , checks if a RequestFuture is there for the request Id , then complete the future with correct response. This way it works as Sync API for the end User.

Any Better Sol. for this

Comment: Are you set on this back-end solution and just need suggestions to give the UI a Sync look and feel, or are you also looking for better options on the domain model side?

Comment: End output required is giving UI a sync api as when we expose such API for integrations async dosent sound good , we are completly open for better options for domain model side

Comment: Yes but you could have an async API with a sync-ish UI look and feel (by polling for instance)

Comment: for our UI it might work , but when exposing the API for Integrations, telling the partners to poll dosen't look like the right approach

Comment: Also people like Salesforce and others must be facing the same issue if something requires a transaction between multiple Aggregate , how they provide the Sync API to the end customer, either they poll on the Server Side and give a Sync feel to the integration partner

Comment: Also from your initial question i think there are some other ways to model the same problem so that one can provide the sync API

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Salesforce use the "aggregate as consistency boundary" rule to begin with? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a synchronous API, I only see two options:

- Design your domain model so that `Lead` creation logic, the "10 leads max" rule and the list of leads for a user are co-located in the same Aggregate root (hint: an [AR can spawn another AR](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)).
- Accept to involve more than one non-new Aggregate in the same transaction.

The tradeoff depends on transactional analysis about the aggregates in question - will reading from them in the same transaction lead to a lot of locking and race conditions?

Comment: I am using Lagom and in that i cannot write on two diff aggregate in the same transaction.  Also in my domain they are actually part of diff. Microservices all together , so anything in same transaction i am unable to visualize

Comment: Also when you say an AR spawn another AR , by that you mean based on event stream of 1 one AR you create another AR

Comment: Also when i case of our lead , do u expose internal state like assigning to user to external users or not

Comment: Sorry, I meant "lead assignment" not "creation". Don't get me wrong, I'm not suggesting to put lead assignment logic in the microservice where `User` lives but in the one where `Lead` lives.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have a `UserLeads` aggregate containing all of a user's assigned Lead IDs and the 10 lead invariant? `Lead` wouldn't have a `UserID` any more but the other way around.

Comment: UserLead Aggregate is not possible as there is a separate microservice which understand user has work capacity and admin configure that a user can work on 2 Lead , 10 Deals at a time and ... . Also lets say even if i create a UserLead Aggregate when user 1 pick a lead and lead is already  assigned to user 2 , then a transaction has to happen between two UserLead Agg. and that also is not possible in Lagom.

Comment: Wait, you have to separate stuff that must happen synchronously and stuff that can be eventually consistent in order to do good modelling. Separate microservices can't be immediately consistent, no matter what. So there's no way the work capacity rules are going to give immediate validation the way you modelled things right now... What did you expect?

Comment: It looks very much like you just split your microservices by entity type and did not do the necessary domain and  transactional analysis with a domain expert to identify what changes together and derive bounded contexts/microservices and aggregates from that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177340/discussion-between-guillaume31-and-techagrammer).